# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects when deployed on Heroku

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, heroku

I am trying to deploy the latest version of my code to Heroku (which works perfectly locally, **the exact same code**) and I see Error 500. When I look at `heroku logs`, I see the following error:

```
2014-06-15T12:41:20.661382+00:00 app[web.1]: [Sun Jun 15 12:41:20.555906 2014] [core:error] [pid 65:tid 139773788280576] [client 10.164.12.48:57546] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I set the LogLevel to debug:

```
heroku config:add LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
```

But I still get the same error. I also tried adding `RewriteBase /` to my .htaccess file in the main folder of CakePHP, as some people suggested:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And I also tried it in the webroot folder, but still no luck!

People also say this could happen due to insufficient permission of `/tmp/` folder, but when I change the permission to read and write Git does not see the change. I even force downgrade PHP when deploying on Heroku!

With all the suggestions, I still find it very weird, because I did not change anything in any configuration files nor did I change any permission on any file. Anyone any idea what could cause this? Please don't refer me to other posts in StackOverflow, as I've already seen all of them.

**Update:**
A rollback to the old code, gets the website working again, but the funny things is that it does not matter what I add to the code (even a line of code or an echo), it crashes the website! So I just want to say that it has nothing to do with what code I have written.

Comment: You can't set an Apache `LogLevel` using such a config var. The closest would be using a [custom config](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#using-a-custom-application-level-apache-configuration) with `LogLevel rewrite:debug` and a few other things (like `DirectoryIndex index.php`) inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/486

The underlying issue was the way requests to `.php` files were proxied to PHP-FPM using default rewrites, which would occasionally interfere with user-land rewrites.

However, what you should really be doing is [set your document root](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#setting-the-document-root) so it's `app/webroot/`, instead of rewriting to that location first (and then having the `.htaccess` in there do another round of rewrites).

Create, add, commit and push a `Procfile` that looks like this:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 app/webroot/
```

Comment: This was killing me until I contacted Herku Support. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you meant .**+** in your second RewriteRule, so it does not apply to requests for / and cause you to loop.

Every time a substitution occurs in RewriteRule in htaccess, the entire set of rules runs again on the substitution.